# Maximo script to send a message to another user?

Tags: jython, maximo

With IBM ICD/Maximo version 7.6.1.2 I am trying to inform a user when an attachment (arriving via a REST call) has finally arrived.

- I have access to the USERID of the requester
- the launchpoint is 'add' on DOCLINKS
- I aim to inform the user using a message box (or something similar) if he/she is still active on the platform
- The whole send/receive action takes more than 10-15 minutes so waiting for a response during the same REST call is not possible. The user sends a POST and later receives a POST.

The problem is, mbo.getUserInfo() points to the username of the external service and not the requester so in my opinion I need to either change the active session or active user in order to be able to use commands like:

```
service.webclientsession().showMessageBox(msggroup,msgkey,params)
```

I need a method or commands to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be by sending a bulletin board message to the user to notify that their file has been uploaded [as shown here](https://github.com/maximo-wiki/maximo-automation-scripts/blob/master/mxc_create_bboard.py)